# iOS UITableViewController didSelectRowAtIndexPath not loading another UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` working just fine with all the content when I tap on one of the cells `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is being call but doesn't go to the next `UITableViewController`. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewHeadersController *detailViewController = [[ViewHeadersController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewHeadersController" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *resultsData = [_response objectForKey:@"results"];
    detailViewController.urlHeaders = [[resultsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I know `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is responding because I see the output of the `NSLog`.

Any of you knows what is going on or why the uitablevicontroller is not switching to the next `UITableViewController`?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Did you push the current view controller as a navigation controller? Or is it the rootViewController of a navigation controller?

Comment: 2 things to check for. 1) Are you sure your current `UIViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`? 2) Are you sure that the `ViewHeaderController` is initialized properly? You could have a misspelling of the name somewhere, or the nib/storyboard is no hooked up right.

Answer (score 0):

I change the line where is navegationController:

```
ViewHeadersController *detailViewController = [[ViewHeadersController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewHeadersController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
NSArray *resultsData = [_response objectForKey:@"results"];
detailViewController.urlHeaders = [[resultsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"];
[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```